# How to make a new line in Wrap Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I use the Wrap Widget to display chat messages, I'm having trouble getting show new line '\n' in Wrap Widgets

show text message:

````
a *bold*
`highlight`
```pre```
```pre1```
a ```pre2```
a *bold*
````

Extract to list widget:
[image]

and then wrap listWidget in Wrap Widget

```
Wrap(
  children: listWidgets,
)
```

[image]

but the Text widget ('\ n') doesn't go as expected

*Does anyone have solution new line in Wrap Widget please help*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use RichText widget:

```
RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: '26 Sep 2020\n\n',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'blablabla',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: i can't use ```RichText``` cause `pre` is box full width

Comment: or you can try this, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/InlineSpan-class.html. Use WidgetSpan for Container with text child and background color grey

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the [`direction`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap/direction.html) property of your `Wrap` widget.

```
Wrap(
   direction: Axis.vertical,
   children: listWidgets,
)
```